# R How to plot a "net interaction effect" (or marginal effect) when there are 'confounding' interactions

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, panel-data

I want to draw the interaction effects between x1 and x2 for the following regression (let y be a positive count variable in a panel dataset)

```
library(lme4)
glmer.repex<-glmer.nb(y ~ x1 + x2 +I(x2^2) + x1:x2 +x1:I(x2^2) + (1|Year), data=repex, nAGQ = 1L)
```

The easy interaction plot is:

```
interaction.plot(x1,x2,y) ; interaction.plot(x1,x2,fitted(test.lmer,ndf, type="response"))
```

Now I want to acknowledge that if x1 changes the values of `x1*x2` and `x1^2` will also change which will change the fitted values. All of this should be taken into account when plotting the net interaction effect. It might e.g. be so that x1 and x2 both are positively correlated with y, but that their interaction attenuates this positive effect, potentially changing the direction of the prediction. This might additionally be conditional on the values of `x1*x2`...

So the simple interaction.plot does not really work anymore because the other variables are affecting the outcome as well. 
Is there an easy way of doing this either with `predict` or `effect` ?

Here is a reproducible example data set (plm.data object) called `repex`

`dput(repex)
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("1", "2", "4", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "13", "15", "16", "17", "18", "20", "22", 
"24", "26", "28", "29", "32", "34", "35", "36", "37", "39", "41", 
"42", "44", "47"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1991", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"), class = "factor"), y = c(5, 10, 6, 9, 9, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7, 12, 13, 0, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 9, 9, 12, 9, 10, 6, 14, 12, 6, 2, 20, 15, 18, 14, 26, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), x1 = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x2 = structure(c(4.22657266700715, 7.07828323739468, 5.58155937520987, 6.09945741088926, 4.98990473760187, 13.1975509132969, 0.136363636363636, 0.164922480620155, 0.981640399790555, 1.61119564479727, 4.27951983102512, 4.52440902710094, 2.41282572727806, 
2.77748331046807, 7.00223921984389, 3.55837337174436, 5.31590575343992, 2.61930006177923, 0.211351052048726, 0.525647451963241, 0.696630753538187, 0.666082288178836, 1.09492110512526, 3.8035303566375, 0.548336215316966, 0.85237681730237, 0.982747572848003, 6.59758768791534, 8.74094242997363, 9.29913186611362, 3.5542234379174, 3.24728026722101, 3.60927964544638, 3.33459121950297, 2.88526780610146, 4.56612429882729, 26.45256036788, 
21.0190838535023, 19.3769702276769, 19.7227148506334, 17.6596029433548, 23.6531530880185, 0.138888888888889, 0.249009205804338, 0.394159544159544, 0.316399286987522, 0.0413533834586466, 3.02315977564407, 3.94214293703149, 1.9143052531528, 3.16707069146414, 5.70642767128218, 4.38285025038957, 4.23425019314604, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0416666666666667, 0), .Dim = 60L, .Dimnames = list(c("1990_ABT", "1991_ABT", "1992_ABT", "1993_ABT", "1994_ABT", "1995_ABT", "1990_AKN", "1991_AKN", "1992_AKN", "1993_AKN", "1994_AKN", "1995_AKN", 
"1990_ALL", "1991_ALL", "1992_ALL", "1993_ALL", "1994_ALL", 
"1995_ALL", "1990_AMG", "1991_AMG", "1992_AMG", "1993_AMG", 
"1994_AMG", "1995_AMG", "1990_AZN", "1991_AZN", "1992_AZN", 
"1993_AZN", "1994_AZN", "1995_AZN", "1990_BAX", "1991_BAX", 
"1992_BAX", "1993_BAX", "1994_BAX", "1995_BAX", "1990_BAY", 
"1991_BAY", "1992_BAY", "1993_BAY", "1994_BAY", "1995_BAY", 
"1990_BIO", "1991_BIO", "1992_BIO", "1993_BIO", "1994_BIO", 
"1995_BIO", "1990_BMS", "1991_BMS", "1992_BMS", "1993_BMS", 
"1994_BMS", "1995_BMS", "1990_ABT", "1990_ABT", "1990_ABT", 
"1990_ABT", "1994_CHU", "1990_ABT")))), .Names = c("ID", 
"Year", "y", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 160L, 
5L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 188L, 12L, 190L, 191L, 
192L, 13L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 22L, 23L, 230L, 
231L, 232L, 233L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 248L, 249L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 276L, 156L, 52L, 158L, 159L, 281L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
295L, 59L, 297L, 588L, 391L, 392L, 393L, 187L, 395L), class = c("plm.dim", 
"data.frame"))`

Thanks!

Comment: At the moment your question is too vague to begin coding. Either update your question with a specific dataset and request regarding a specific set of value or delete the question here and repost on CrossValidated.com (Adso let it be known that you description of an interaction as "negative" is not really meaningful. You are correct in thinking that you should be using 'predict' to address this question.

Comment: Furthermore, you are using the R formula interface incorrectly. In R you cannot use x2^2 and expect to model the squared value as a separate predictor.